# Nullpointer exception when creating object of JFileChooser

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, java-7

I'm getting a Nullpointer exception on the following simple code:

```
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    }

}
```

It's the JFileChooser constructor that throws. I'm getting the following exception message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getFileSystemPath(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$10.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$10.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The only thing I found when googling the problem are reports about a regression in Java6, so the first thing I did was update to JDK 7u45 and threw out all the old version junk. Now JRE 7u45 and JDK 7u45 are the only ones installed.

A call to `System.getProperty("java.runtime.version")` returns `1.7.0_45-b18` so I ought to be up to date.

I'm still getting the same error, though. I'm running the code on Eclipse and have never linked any libraries but the standard JRE.

Any clues?

**Edit**: That's the call stack when trying to step into the JFileChooser constructor:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended)   
    FileNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String) line: 264   
    FileNotFoundException(Exception).<init>(String) line: not available 
    FileNotFoundException(IOException).<init>(String) line: not available   
    FileNotFoundException.<init>(String, String) line: not available    
    FileInputStream.open(String) line: not available [native method]    
    FileInputStream.<init>(File) line: not available    
    Toolkit$1.run() line: not available 
    AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>) line: not available [native method]  
    Toolkit.initAssistiveTechnologies() line: not available 
    Toolkit.<clinit>() line: not available
    Component.<clinit>() line: not available
    Main.main(String[]) line: 6
```

**Edit 2**: I've found out which part of `JFileChooser` causes the problem: The second optional parameter for the constructor is a `FileSystemView` which bugs out. If I write my own, it works:

```
static public class DummyFSV extends FileSystemView
    {

        public SingleRootFileSystemView(File root)
        {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public File createNewFolder(File containingDir)
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public File getDefaultDirectory()
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public File getHomeDirectory()
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public File[] getRoots()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    ...
    JFileChooser = new JFileChooser( new DummyFVS() );
```

I can't do much with it, of course. The default FSV I get via `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView()` is a `WindowsFileSystemView` (which fits my OS), but it NPEs out as soon as it's being used.

The dummy FSV actually brings up the file dialog, but I can't navigate my folders since it's not the Windows FSV. So it's only a very limited use.

Comment: Seems to work for me.  Try exporting it as runnable Jar and run it via the command line?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Just did. Same error.

Comment: What if you strive to run it in the Swing thread via `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){....});`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Same error, still.

Comment: at a guess your jre is corrupted does it happen with another jre?

Comment: Problem is, works just fine for me...What OS?

Comment: @BevynQ Windows 7. If this thread doesn't bring anything up I'll remove JRE/JDK/Eclipse and do a clean reinstall.

Comment: @s3rius i have same system with no problem. Have you tried break pointing in the NullPointerException Constructor?

Comment: @BevynQ I've edited the post with the call stack when I tried to step into the constructor. There's no source code to look at, though. I see there's a FileNoFoundException being thrown, but I have no idea how to interpret that.

Comment: I did a complete reinstallation of Java7 now. Same error, still. I don't get it.

Comment: @s3rius Did you ever solve this? I ran into the same error with JRE 1.8. It seems to be an open issue in the Java platform according to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6973685. The problem is to reproduce the bug because on most Windows installation it does not occur.

Comment: @fhissen I think the problem went away by removing the 64bit JRE and switching to the 32bit version. It's been a while, however, so I don't exactly remember.

Comment: Just for the record... in case someone steps over this question. In my case, I could not reproduce the bug. The customer having the problem had tinkered around with Windows' special folders (libraries), so he ran into the problem. However, I could create a custom `FileSystemView` which worked in his case. It's really bad hacking...:

[Available on GitHub](https://github.com/fhissen/CrococryptFile/blob/master/CrococryptFile/common/org/fhissen/utils/ui/SwingHacks_FileSystemView.java)

Answer (score 0):

Is this on a vanilla Windows machine? Which windows edition? Any registry tweaks applied that change the Explorer namespace or the view of the File Open dialog?

I have seen similar issues where third party tools are installed that try to manipulate the view of the File Open dialog, which seem to create some inconsistent state that causes a NullPointerException in GetFileSystemPath when trying to obtain the path of "Network Neigborhood".